# Making a new list of dictionary values whose keys match items in a seperate list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

This dictionary stores the farm animals as the key and their location as the value.

```
id_name_dict = {
    'cat': 'barn', 'dog': 'field', 'chicken': 'coop',
    'sheep': 'pasture', 'horse': 'barn', 'cow': 'barn'
}
```

This list stores the names of the farm animals whose location I want to know

```
wanted_farm_animals = ['cat,', 'dog', 'horse']
```

The desired output is a new list with the wanted_farm_animals location

```
n = ['barn', 'field', 'barn']
```

Here is the code I tried to do this

```
n = []
for animal, location in id_name_dict.items():
    for a in wanted_farm_animals:
        if a == animal:
            n.append(location)
print(n)
```

However, the output is not complete. It is only

```
['field', 'barn']
```

How do I get the correct desired output?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Given your username you must be an expert concerning farm animals ;)

Comment: There's an extra comma after "cat" in the wanted_farm_animals list

Comment: got it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How about simple list comprehension?

```
id_name_dict = {
    'cat': 'barn', 'dog': 'field', 'chicken': 'coop',
    'sheep': 'pasture', 'horse': 'barn', 'cow': 'barn'
}    
wanted_farm_animals = ['cat', 'dog', 'horse']

result = [v for k,v in id_name_dict.items() if k in wanted_farm_animals]
# ['barn', 'field', 'barn']
```

Comment: @mkrieger1, what if some `animal` is not in `id_name_dict` ? Like `wanted_farm_animals = ['cat,', 'dog', 'horse', 'mouse']`. So we are relying on matched/intersected keys

Answer (score 0):

You can map the `wanted_farm_animals` list to the `dict.get` method bound to the `id_name_dict` dict:

```
n = list(map(id_name_dict.get, wanted_farm_animals))
```

By using the `dict.get` method you would get a default value of `None` instead of a `KeyError` exception for an item that's in the `wanted_farm_animals` list but not in the keys of the `id_name_dict` dict.